# Rebind a listview from a jQuery iframe

Tags: jquery, firefox, caching, thickbox

I have a listview that includes links to open an iframe with jQuery and thickbox.  This new window allows the user to edit the field information with the iframe. Update button -

```
<input type="submit" name="bUpdateDate" value="Update" 
onclick="self.parent.location.reload(true);self.parent.tb_remove();"
id="bUpdateDate" />
```

This refresh works well in IE, but both Firefox and Chrome do not rebind the listview.  I have tried meta tags for no cache, and HttpCacheability.NoCache and IIS header content expiration, but nothing seems to be able to force a Firefox refresh.  How can I get my listview to rebind from the child iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that working for me is found here: http://www.zdima.net/blog/archives/398

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.3.3 when released will have better support for iFrame binding http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/05/14/jquery-edge-better-support-for-other-windows-and-documents

You may be able to get the latest bits and have more success.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, does

```
top.location.reload(true)
```

work?

Comment: Same result as described above.